# how to mix 2 tables(A,B) in 1 table (AB) with sql (db2 dialog) with special order between records

Tags: sql, db2

Please how to mix 2 tables(A,B) in 1 table(AB) with special order.

It is 2 tables, A and B with only 1 col. So it is a list/array.

I must order the row like this:
A.col1,A.col1,B.col1,B.col1,A.col1,A.col1,B.col1,B.col1,A.col1,A.col1,B.col1,B.col1 and so on.

To see it easily, it must be:
A,A,B,B,A,A,B,B,A,A

So 2 row from A, 2 row from B, 2 row from A, 2 row from B and so on

I would prefer with db2 sql dialog language, but if it isnt specific would be useful in any sql dialog

thanks

Comment: In SQL there are _rows_ and _columns_, not records or fields...

Comment: can you disclose data in field1 by which i will try to suggest a query?

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious of anything trying to interleave records in this specific of an order, it smacks of an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  If the records are "synonymous" (identical in concept), then the apparent order shouldn't matter.  If you're trying to do something like tie records from `B` to their parent records in `A`, the proper solution would be a join, and to add them as extra columns (not as rows).  There's other problems here: what if there's an odd number of rows?  Fewer groups in one of the tables?

Comment: Also, SQL is inherently _unordered_, because it works on sets (all data matching a specific criteria).  If you dump the rows into another table, your apparent order is going to disappear - in fact, the optimizer might decide to get all rows from A, then all rows from B, because ordering is an expensive operation (and it might be able to tell it isn't required).

Comment: @jarlh, ok agree ;), changed

Comment: @kiran gadhe they are strings, for example A.col1 have: capa,capb,capc,capd and B.col1 have cape,capf,capg,caph , so I want get result table like this: capa,capb,cape,capf,capc,capd,capg,caph. Getting 2 from each list

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, no, same amount in both tables. You give me an idea add an extra column to do a join and get the order in natural way? ok will try this approach

Comment: @raúlandrés - No, now I'm even **more** suspicious.  If the rows look anything like your example there, why aren't you returning them in their natural order - that is, ordered by the column itself.  Also, if you can guarantee that there's exactly the same number of rows (and only one column of data, too), I'm guessing this data is being pulled from somewhere else - could you go to the original source?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Field1 FROM
(SELECT Field1, 1 AS S, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS N, FLOOR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER()/2) AS G FROM A
UNION ALL 
 SELECT Field1, 2 AS S, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS N, FLOOR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER()/2) AS G FROM B)
ORDER BY G, S, N
```

That should work in DB2. Unfortunately I don't have a DB2 database handy to test it so the code goes without any warranty.